# Estimate of total number of oncogenic mutations

Tags: genetics, cancer

So there are a number of ways point mutations can hyperactivate or inactivate genes. But realistically there are only some small number of point mutations ever observed for a particular gene in cancers. An example is the JAK2 mutation: c.1849G>T p.V617F chr9:5073770 which is almost the only JAK2 base substitution observed in leukemias.

Is there some estimate of the number of substitution loci ever observed in cancers?

Comment: you can visit the TCGA website, but be warned navigating that mess is a giant pain

Comment: @KoustavPal yeah I've played with TCGA a lot, but that I can find there is no sum total estimate of this.